# What is the difference and relationship between LockWord and MarkWord

Tags: android, jvm

In art/runtime/monitor.cc we can see LockWord .LockWord.GetState have "kUnlocked","kThinLocked","kFatLocked"and"kHashCode" state, in this code, object could be lock or unlock. LockWord contains lock information, thread id,lock count and so on.It's very similar to MarkWord.so i have some question

1. What is the relationship between markword and lockWord.
2. what is the relationship between Objec.shadow$*monitor*(android add) and LockWord.

This question has troubled me for a long time, thank you very much for your answer

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:art/runtime/mirror/object.cc;drc=master;l=184

Comment: LockWord is in Android Runtime; markWord is in the HotSpot JVM. These are independent concepts. They serve for a similar purpose in the implementation of different virtual machines.

Comment: @apangin Thanks for your answer , so LockWord & MarkWord are just different name  for the same thing.